# Is there any calculation result for quandle homology group?

Tags: homology-cohomology, knot-theory, group-cohomology

I'm investigating the calculation result for the quandle homology group of a dihedral quandle.

First of all, I know that the result for odd order(for odd n in $H_k^Q(R_n;\mathbb{Z})$) is well known, so I am investigating the case of even order.

The following results were obtained by referring to the quhomology package written in R language and some papers.

$H_2^Q(R_4;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z^2+Z_2^2}$

$H_3^Q(R_4;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z^2+Z_2^4}$

$H_4^Q(R_4;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z^2+Z_2^{10}}$

$H_2^Q(R_6;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z^2}$

$H_3^Q(R_6;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z^2+Z_3^2}$

$H_2^Q(R_8;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z^2+Z_2^2}$

$H_3^Q(R_8;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z^2+Z_2^2+Z_8^2}$

I don't know if it's the limit of computational power or if there's an error in the quhomology package, but I couldn't get any more results.

I'm curious about more calculation results. Are there any more known results?